# WPF How to disable blend mode? Drawing on top of controls blends the colors like overlay mode

Tags: wpf, drawing, colors, blending

I'm trying to draw a line on top of an existing control but it blends the colors together. All I find is tutorial on how to make fancy blending mode but all I want is draw a solid color line over my controls but even the solidColorBrush doesn't behave like I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting an Opacity setting on your brushes?

**Edit**
I had a bit of a look and apparently Opacity seems to be cumulative as you inherit through controls.

See [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/Tc10012009211641PM/Tc.aspx) link, where he applies opacity to both the button content and the button itself. Can you follow the advice of the SO link you posted to remove the opacity on a parent object?

Comment: Yes opacity="1" but it has no effect. It seems like it draws at opacity 0.5 even though it's set at 1. I also tried to remove  OpacityMask but with no success.

Comment: Can the brush inherit opacity from it's parent container?
Like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982103/opaque-element-in-a-transparent-in-wpf