# WPF transparency changing, when elements are bound

Tags: wpf, xaml

A `VisualBrush` is used to fill a `Rectangle` in a WPF window.

It fills by binding its `Visual` property to a non-transparent element in the window.

How can the `Rectangle` fill be made transparent, so that what is behind the window is visible through it, without making other elements transparent as well?

Roughly following the how-to on creating reflection effects [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970263(v=vs.110).aspx), and looking at SO questions about making specific elements opaque with a transparent window [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982103/opaque-element-in-a-transparent-in-wpf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650576/how-do-you-override-the-opacity-of-a-parent-control-in-wpf), I've come up with the following in XAML. However, I cannot seem to make the `Rectangle` transparent, without also making the `TextBlock` it is bound to also transparent.

```
<!-- Window.AllowsTransparency is set to true,
    so WindowStyle must also be set to None.
    Background is set to Transparent so child
    elements have capability to be transparent
    to what is behind the window. -->

<Window x:Class="XAMLViewTests.TransparentTestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TransparentTestWindow"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

        <!-- Two elements: TextBlock and Rectangle -->

        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Background="White">This is some text.</TextBlock>

        <Rectangle Height="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <!-- Fill rectangle with a Visual element bound to TextBlock,
            so it shows exactly the same as TextBlock. Transforms, effects, etc
            can now be performed on the Visual. -->

            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="None" Visual="{Binding ElementName=textBlock}">
                </VisualBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? If you set the Fill to an element, it will display that element as background. If you want a transparent rectangle, why dont you simply set it to transparent?

Comment: Rectangle background needs to be transparent, but what is inside needs to be opaque or at least only partially transparent.

Comment: What exactly should be transparent inside the rectangle? The background of the textblock?

Comment: @Dominik yes that is correct.

Comment: @Aaron: Better post a picture of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the textblock as background and make its background transparent just for the binding.

What you can do though is setting another textblock as background and bind all relevant values to the original textblock:

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
    <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <TextBlock Background="Transparent" 
                        Text="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=Text}" 
                        Width="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Rectangle.Fill>
```

Comment: Using Transparent element as a Brush? This won't render anything, imho.

Comment: The element is not transparent, only the background